# React testing: mocking useRef

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm relatively new to react testing, but currently trying to use a few examples I found on the net to mock a React hook - specifically useRef.

The code below is what I found in a couple of accepted examples, but I cant understand why the following error is being generated. It 'feels' as though I'm not mocking what I think I am (i.e. useRef) but I'm struggling to understand why.

[image: mock useRef error]

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the version of the jest

Comment: Thanks slideshowp2, I've got version 5.16.4 being installed by npm

Answer (score 0):

You can skip last 2 lines

[image]

Just do this before running your test

```js
jest.mock("react", () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual("react"),
    useRef: () => {
      return {
        current: { width: 100 }
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks Patrik. What you've suggested definitely seems to be a step forwards, but might not be all of the answer...let me add some further context(which possibly should have been in the original question).


I was attempting to mock useRef as a mechanism to manipulate the output of getBoundingClientRect() in a code snippet similar to: 


someRef = useRef(0);
someRect = someRef .current.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(someRect);

Comment: but the output of the console.log statement still shows 'width' as being 0 after inserting your code snippet. I completely agree that what you've suggested is a step forwards though...I'm not seeing the original error message any longer. 

Would the above info help with any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: If your code is using `getBoundingClientRect()` and calculating some width from it I think you might need to mock `getBoundingClientRect()` too

Comment: It would be of great help if you could share your test suite & the component under test